# Finding days between 2 days in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am facing some problem in finding the days between 2 dates.

The scenario is as follow :

```
time = Time.new
enddate_timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")               
startdate = @logInfo.updated_at   #here updated_at is the column in the db .
```

What is the best way to find the days ?

Comment: not sure what exactly you are asking. Find what days? The number of them? The count of them?  The Interval of time that has passed?  Need more information on what exactly you would like the output to be?  Also would something like `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` be  what you are looking for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words_to_now

Comment: @Doon maybe my English is bad but what is the difference between `The number of them?` and `The count of them?`

Comment: sorry I mean the count of them and then names of them not the number.

Comment: Do you want to use 'time_ago_in_words'? Refer: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.where(["date(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.yesterday, Date.tomorrow]
```

More details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions. A possibility is to create a Range with the dates, then convert the range into an array

```
# set the boundaries
today = Time.current
past  = 5.days.ago
```

Note that both boundaries are time instances. We should cast them into dates. I used time(s) because your column is a time.

```
range = past.to_date..today.to_date 
# => Sun, 29 Dec 2013..Fri, 03 Jan 2014
```

Use `to_a` to expand the range getting all the days

```
range.to_a
# => [Sun, 29 Dec 2013, Mon, 30 Dec 2013, Tue, 31 Dec 2013, Wed, 01 Jan 2014, Thu, 02 Jan 2014, Fri, 03 Jan 2014]

range.count
# => 6
```

You can also enumerate them

```
range.each { |day| puts day.day }
29
30
31
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
now    = Time.now
future = Time.now + 100 days

while now < future
  now = now + 1.day
  puts now
end
```

This will give you the dates, not the days count.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But this is not what exactly I want. I want the difference between 2 dynamic dates instead.

Comment: use this code on your dynamic dates instead. This was only an example for grasping the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
(startdate.beginning_of_day..enddate_timestamp.to_time.beginning_of_day).step(1.day) do |day|    
  puts day
end
```

P.S: Performance wise it's not good.